# Как в node.js узнать дату изменения файла?

Tags: node.js

Возможно ли в node.js узнать дату последнего изменения файла или директории?

Comment: @eicto: а можно немного подробнее? Сделал вот так -  
```
console.log(fs.stat('path', function(args){
 console.log(args)
}))
```
Но выводит undefined...

Comment: первый параметр callback - error если хотите все аргументы, просто console.log(arguments);

Comment: @eicto: Спасибо, получилось! А Вы не можете объяснить, в чем разница между eicto, mtime, ctime? Ведь это и есть время изменения файла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[да](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback)

вот этот пример прекрасно работает:

```
var path="/tmp/";
var fs=require('fs');
fs.stat(path, function(err,stat){
    console.log(err,stat);
});
```

выдает что-то типа

```
null { dev: 29,
  mode: 17407,
  nlink: 25,
  uid: 0,
  gid: 0,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 6446,
  size: 1660,
  blocks: 0,
  atime: Sun Aug 03 2014 11:48:21 GMT+0000 (Z),
  mtime: Sun Aug 03 2014 12:09:14 GMT+0000 (Z),
  ctime: Sun Aug 03 2014 12:09:14 GMT+0000 (Z) }
```

Comment: @eicto: Спасибо, получилось! А Вы не можете объяснить, в чем разница между eicto, mtime, ctime? Ведь это и есть время изменения файла?  
Пока писал, Вы ответили:) Но вопрос все равно актуальный)) Спасибо!

Comment: @vas гляньте кстати в исследования, ато я вас вчера обманул слегка

http://hashcode.ru/research/350567/javascript-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-js

Comment: @eicto: Спасибо! Я в иследованиях причину написал.

Comment: eicto это я, mtime - время модификации, ctime - время изменения.

обычно ctime нельзя выставлять вручную (никому кроме рута, руту все можно при желании) а mtime как  раз выставляют вручную, типичный пример - распаковка из архива  - mtime будет как в архиве, а ctime сегодняшний.